# Run PostgreSQL Stored Procedure in Intellij

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea, plpgsql, datagrip

I use database plugin in **Intellij**. When I try to run the sp for testing, I get the generated code but not working.

```
do $$
declare
    result refcursor = 'generated_result_cursor';
begin
    open result for call some_pkg$some_proc(
        i_lat := null,
        i_lon := null,
        o_result := null,
        o_city_tier := null
);
end
$$;
fetch all in "generated_result_cursor";
close "generated_result_cursor";
```

Try to run the piece of script, I get:

```
[34000] ERROR: cursor "generated_result_cursor" does not exist
```

Comment: A `do` block has no result, not even `OUT` parameters I think. You need to run `call some_proc(..)` directly and make sure autocommit is turned **off**

Comment: How do I print the result? o_result

Comment: Using `fetch all` - but directly after the `call ...` statement (if IntelliJ supports that)

Comment: A **much** easier way would be to convert the procedure into a function that returns a result. Then you can simply run `select * from function()` without the hassle of refcursors and out parameters. Procedures aren't meant to return things.

Comment: Could you specify exact version of DataGrip you use? 
Also, do you copy code to a console or execute it from `Execute Routine` dialog?